# Local install of powershell instead of https://shell.azure.com?

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to use Powershell to create VMs on Azure because I cannot find the necessary functionality on the portal (or get it to work).

Is it possible to administrate Azure using a local instance of powershell rather than the online version?

If so how do you install the relevant cmdlets?
For example how do I install New-AzVm?

I am running RedHat linux and have (somewhat reluctantly) installed pwsh via the instructions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-7).

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/?view=azps-4.5.0

Comment: Yes that link does it - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-4.5.0.
In fact I don't need Powershell at all. I can learn Azure CLI instead. Doh! 
Make it an answer and I'll accept if you want the rep.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you are on Linux and haven't stated any specific requirement for `Azure PowerShell` I'd suggest to use `Azure CLI` instead. Installation instructions can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-yum?view=azure-cli-latest).